# Camel3-Blueprint-Testing fails with error 'Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed'

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

Im trying to implement JUnit-Test with Camel-Blueprints. I used Camel-Blueprint-Testing with Camel2 before without major issues, but with Camel3 it simple dont work and throws strange Errors. I created a simple Sample-Project: https://github.com/CrEaK/camel3-blueprint-testing
As you can see the Project is quiet simple. Im using Java8. When I start Class CamelBlueprintTest as Testrun i get the following output: https://gist.github.com/CrEaK/7b323c2d6e76cf06719b3eaa05523e29

The last error with 'Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed' is very strange.

Has anyone any idea why this failes so badly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try moving your blueprint file to standard location for OSGi blueprints which is `resources/OSGI-INF/blueprint` then using the following `getBlueprintDescriptor` with `CamelBlueprintTestSupport`. The issue could be that your `blueprints/test.xml` is missing path-separator at the begining of the string.

```java
@Override
protected String getBlueprintDescriptor() {
    return "/OSGI-INF/blueprint/test.xml";
}
```

Looked at your sample Sample-project and noticed that it is missing **maven-bundle-plugin** and **packaging** isn't set to **bundle** which can cause issues. I generally recommend people to use the available archetypes for OSGi/Karaf blueprint projects.

- [karaf-blueprint-archetype](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.karaf.archetypes/karaf-blueprint-archetype)
- [camel-archetype-blueprint](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel.archetypes/camel-archetype-blueprint)

You can also look apache camel github repository for "examples" like [this](https://github.com/apache/camel-karaf/tree/camel-karaf-3.14.1/tests/camel-blueprint-test) test shows how to setup CamelBlueprintTest.

The exception `org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to start bundle` with CamelTestSupport usually means that there's something wrong with how blueprint or test has been setup. For me this is usually caused by returning incorrect config pid from `useOverridePropertiesWithConfigAdmin` or incorrect path with `getBlueprintDescriptor`. Jars are basically archives so the cryptic `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed` exception is probably related to failure to find the blueprint.